# how to speed-up a very slow pandas apply function?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a very large pandas dataset, and at some point I need to use the following function

```
def proc_trader(data):
    data['_seq'] = np.nan
    # make every ending of a roundtrip with its index
    data.ix[data.cumq == 0,'tag'] = np.arange(1, (data.cumq == 0).sum() + 1)
    # backfill the roundtrip index until previous roundtrip;
    # then fill the rest with 0s (roundtrip incomplete for most recent trades)
    data['_seq'] =data['tag'].fillna(method = 'bfill').fillna(0)
    return data['_seq']
    # btw, why on earth this function returns a dataframe instead of the series `data['_seq']`??
```

and I use apply

```
reshaped['_spell']=reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])[['cumq']].apply(proc_trader)
```

Obviously, I cannot share the data here, but do you see a bottleneck in my code? Could it be the `arange` thing? There are many `name-productid` combinations in the data.

Minimal Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

reshaped= pd.DataFrame({'trader' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a'],'stock' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b'], 'day' :[0,1,2,4,5,10,1],'delta':[10,-10,15,-10,-5,5,0] ,'out': [1,1,2,2,2,0,1]})


reshaped.sort_values(by=['trader', 'stock','day'], inplace=True)
reshaped['cumq']=reshaped.groupby(['trader', 'stock']).delta.transform('cumsum')
reshaped['_spell']=reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])[['cumq']].apply(proc_trader).reset_index()['_seq']
```

Comment: have you tried line-profiling the code?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: there is a library for that, and work wonderfully, check it out! I would take a look, but it is probably data-dependent.

https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Comment: I think more and more that `fillna` is pretty slow

Comment: if I have to take a bet I would say it's probably the `.ix` indexing and assigning, but again, it's hard to say without seeing the results of the profiling

Comment: Your code gives me `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`.  Is anything missing?

Comment: same here, `TypeError`

Comment: one second, sorry about that. posting the correct version in 2min

Comment: ok I think I know whats wrong. the last line `reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])[['cumq']].apply(proc_trader)` returns the correct output, but with a multiindex. Maybe thats why I cannot assign this output to the column reshaped['_spell']? how should I modify my function?

Comment: OK problem fixed. Please see edited post. but why on earth does my function return a dataframe instead of the series `data['seq']`? Is that a bug or I am missing something??

Comment: yes but I dont understand the logic here. I am returning a column right? why am I ending with the whole dataframe?

Comment: because yes, not only its a multiindex, but it contains multiple columns (i.e. a dataframe). try for yourself: just print this `reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])[['cumq']].apply(proc_trader)`

Comment: No, it's a triple indexed Series, but I see what you mean b/c how it displays appears to be a double index with two columsn.  It's not tho.  ;-)

Comment: haha OK nice trick, PANDAS! thanks buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really fancy here, just tweaked in a couple of places.  There is really no need to put in a function, so I didn't.  On this tiny sample data, it's about twice as fast as the original.

```
reshaped.sort_values(by=['trader', 'stock','day'], inplace=True)
reshaped['cumq']=reshaped.groupby(['trader', 'stock']).delta.cumsum()
reshaped.loc[ reshaped.cumq == 0, '_spell' ] = 1
reshaped['_spell'] = reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])['_spell'].cumsum()
reshaped['_spell'] = reshaped.groupby(['trader','stock'])['_spell'].bfill().fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
   day  delta  out stock trader  cumq  _spell
0    0     10    1     a      a    10     1.0
1    1    -10    1     a      a     0     1.0
2    2     15    2     a      a    15     2.0
3    4    -10    2     a      a     5     2.0
4    5     -5    2     a      a     0     2.0
5   10      5    0     a      a     5     0.0
6    1      0    1     b      a     0     1.0
```